# How to fix error of PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in kotlin language?

Tags: android, kotlin

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fikriapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="FikriApp"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="View.SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is my manifest code, I want to change the main launcher from MainActivity to my SplashScreen but after I change it, I am not able to debug it because of an error from the manifest. It's Kotlin, not java

Comment: Can you add full error , also check if the `View.SplashScreen` is correct package path .

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <activity android:name="View.SplashScreen"
> ```

This is a problem. The package parser that decodes the manifest at installation time expects the package names to be in lowercase, for example `view.SplashScreen`. The java class name can be in UpperCamelCase.

If you want the package name be relative to your top-level package `com.example.fikriapp`, then also add a `.` prefix like `.view.SplashScreen`.